# iOS: UILabel is not centered while expanding view with UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

Tags: ios, autolayout, uiviewanimationtransition

I am trying to present modally a view when tapping a button, that would have at first the same frame than the button, and then expanding to end up full screen, all this using `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`.

Here is my code:

**Expandable Base**

```
class ExpandableBase: UIViewController {

    var senderFrame: CGRect = .zero    
    @IBOutlet weak var fullScreenPopupView: UIView?

    @IBAction func dismiss() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

**Transitioning Delegate extension**

```
extension ExpandableBase: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    public func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return ExpandableBasePresenter()
    }

    public func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return ExpandableBaseDismisser()
    }

}  

private final class ExpandableBasePresenter: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    public func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.8
    }

    public func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let toViewController: ExpandableBase = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to) as! ExpandableBase
        let duration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        toViewController.view.frame = containerView.frame
        containerView.addSubview(toViewController.view)
        let finishFrame = toViewController.fullScreenPopupView?.frame
        toViewController.fullScreenPopupView?.frame = toViewController.senderFrame
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.3, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .layoutSubviews, animations: {
            toViewController.fullScreenPopupView?.frame = finishFrame!
        }) { result in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(result)
        }
    }

}

private final class ExpandableBaseDismisser: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    public func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.4
    }

    public func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let fromViewController: ExpandableBase = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from) as! ExpandableBase
        let duration = self.transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.1, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .layoutSubviews, animations: {
            fromViewController.fullScreenPopupView?.frame = fromViewController.senderFrame
        }) { result in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(result)
        }
    }

}
```

A simple view using this, presenting a label and a dismiss button:

```
final class ExpandableSimpleView: ExpandableBase {

    init(from initialFrame: CGRect) {
        super.init(nibName: "ExpandableSimpleView", bundle: .main)
        self.senderFrame = initialFrame
        self.transitioningDelegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NOPE")
    }

    static func present(fromInitialFrame initialFrame: CGRect) {
        let expandableSimpleView = ExpandableSimpleView(from: initialFrame)
        expandableSimpleView.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext  
        AppDelegateTopMostViewController.present(expandableSimpleView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        //AppDelegateTopMostViewController is a global reference to the top-most view controller of the app            
    }

}
```

Here is the corresponding XIB:

[image]

And how I present this from the parent view controller:

```
@IBAction func openSimpleView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    ExpandableSimpleView.present(fromInitialFrame: sender.frame)
}
```

And here are some screenshots showing how this view expands:

[image]

Although the view expands fine, the label is not centered as it should be. I don't understand why.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT**: following matt's answer, I have made the following changes in `animateTransition`'s presenter.

```
    toViewController.fullScreenPopupView!.transform = 

    toViewController.fullScreenPopupView!.transform.scaledBy(x: toViewController.senderFrame.width / toViewController.view.bounds.width, y: toViewController.senderFrame.height / toViewController.view.bounds.height)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {
        toViewController.fullScreenPopupView!.transform = .identity
    }, completion: nil)
```

Now the animation is fine, but I'm facing another issue: the button in the view is not clickable any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Your animation is wrong. Do not start with a small frame and animate an expansion of the frame. Start with a small *transform* (e.g. x and y scale values of 0.1) and expand the transform (to `.identity`).

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer, I understand this. However, although the animation is now fine, I'm facing another issue: the "Dismiss" button on my view is not clickable anymore. Please see my post's edit.

Comment: Was the button clickable before you changed the animation?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with shrinking or growing the parent view.

You don't have to animate the actual views. You can create and remove temporary views. Hide the actual view and reveal it during takedown.

I suggest that you animate the UILabel separately. It doesn't have to shrink or grow. It merely has to remain stationary. Place a temporary UILabel over the original, hide the original, and perform the animation. Reverse the process during takedown.